# How do I appropriately put and use project resources with a built jar?

Tags: java, jar, relative-path

I have a project having the following folder:

resources/xml-schemata/someXMLschema.xsd

A class inside my project uses this xml schema to validate xml files before importing them.

This class has a local variable pointing out the schema path:

```
schemaFilePath = "resources" + File.separator + "xml-schemata" + File.separator + "someXMLschema.xsd"
```

Of course this works locally.

Now I want to put my tool in a jar to give to other people.

But the project using the jar can't find the schema, because of maybe two things:

- The jar build process has removed the resources folder so that the xml-schemata folder is in the jar root folder.
- The project doesn't even look inside the used jar, but assumes a local resources/xml-schemata folder.

Which of these could be the problem and how could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 File f1 = new File("..\\..\\..\\config.properties");
```

this path trying to access  file is in Project directory then just access  file like this.

```
File f=new File("filename.txt");
```

if your file is in `OtherSources/Resources`

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("relative path");//-> relative path from resources folder
```

also, most impotently, read and print the current directory:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

that way you'll know what's the relative path you need and it will be easier for you to understand if you are trying to read from a bad path or the resources you need aren't there