# How can I set a class to always search in its own project folder for a given path?

Tags: java, eclipse, path, resources, dependencies

This is a follow-up to the question
[How do I appropriately put and use project resources with a built jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440559/how-do-i-appropriately-put-and-use-project-resources-with-a-built-jar)

So again we have the setup:

- a project A having

  - a resources folder at the project root containing an xml schema
  - a class in this project that uses the schema during xml validation

    - this class uses the relative path "resources" + File.separator + SCHEMA-NAME
- another project B dependent on project A

  - which uses the above class
  - no resources folder

When I run project B Eclipse complains about not finding a file at the path specified, because it looks inside of project B's root folder using the path of the project A class. How can I set the class to always look in its own project folder?

What is the best practice for this setup? Is this normal usage? Am I expected to provide project A as a jar for project B?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a resource that is in the same package as your class, you can do so as

```
YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("path/to/other/resource");
```

There is no preceding `/` because the path is relative to the package of the class `YourClass`. This is explained in the javadoc of [`Class#getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the
>   given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of
>   the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'. Otherwise,
>   the absolute name is of the following form: modified_package_name/name
>
> Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object
>   with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

For example, for the fully qualified class `com.mycompany.business.YourClass`, it would appear it the classpath at

```
classpath-root/
    schemas.xsd // some resource
    com/
        /mycompany
            /business
                YourClass.class // your class
                /schemas
                    your-class-schema.xsd // some resource
```

You would access `your-class-schema.xsd` as

```
YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("schemas/your-class-schema.xsd");
```

You would access `schemas.xsd` as

```
YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/schemas.xsd");
```

If a project A is depending on a project B, the classpath of A is including all the class files and resources of B.

```
classpath-root-A/
    /com
        /project
            /a
                /classes
    /com
        /project
            /B
                /classes
```

You would apply the same logic to access the resources in the "imported" B project. You can provide B as a jar to the classpath of A. When you do that, the classpath will be resolved as the example above.